# Faster use of Condition for a large array (see the example)

Tags: list-manipulation, map, conditional

Here is the example/problem.

I have a array of $n$ random number.

```
n = 2000;
p = RandomReal[{0, 9}, n];
```

I have to create a $n\times n$ sparse matrix with $(i,j)$th element given by this condition

$m_{i,j} = \begin{array}{ll}
a(p_i-p_j)&2<|p_i-p_j|<3 \\
b(p_i-p_j)&5<|p_i-p_j|<6 
\end{array}$

A brutal way to do it is using `If` or `Piecewise`

```
f1[x_, y_] := If[2 < Abs[x - y] < 3, a[x-y], If[5 < Abs[x - y] < 6, b[x-y], 0]]
SparseArray@Table[f1[p[[i]], p[[j]]], {i, n}, {j, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {24.858066, Null}

```
f2[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{a[x-y], 2 < Abs[x - y] < 3}, {b[x-y], 5 < Abs[x - y] < 6}}]
SparseArray@Table[f2[p[[i]], p[[j]]], {i, n}, {j, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {26.741343, Null}

And of course `Map` works much faster

```
SparseArray@Partition[
If[2 < # < 3, a[#], If[5 < # < 6, b[#], 0]] & /@ 
 Flatten[Abs[# - p] & /@ p], n]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {7.797710, Null}

(I don't know how to use `Map` in this kind of 2D array so I combined `Flatten` and `Partition`.)

However I can `Parallelize` the `Table` and reduce the time to ~1/8th (I have to use the Workstation in my office) and apparently it looks like the `If` will be a winner. `ParallelMap` doesn't show similar reduction rate in time.

```
SparseArray@ParallelTable[f1[p[[i]], p[[j]]], {i, n}, {j, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {13.573756, Null}

```
SparseArray@Partition[
ParallelMap[If[2 < # < 3, a[#], If[5 < # < 6, b[#], 0]] &,
 Flatten[Abs[# - p] & /@ p]], n]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {8.580731, Null}

So what would be the optimised (to minimise time) way to do the job?

For my actual problem `n~10000` and `a` and `b` are combination of trigonometric and arithmetic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced `a[#]` with `Abs[#]` and `b[#]` with `Abs[#]` in your fastest solution. It took 7.8 seconds to evaluate. The following takes 0.085 seconds to evaluate and gives the same result:

```
m = Compile[{{p, _Real, 1}},
   Outer[Which[
      2 < Abs[# - #2] < 3, Abs[# - #2],
      5 < Abs[# - #2] < 6, Abs[# - #2],
      True, 0
      ] &, p, p], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed"}];

m[p] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* Out: 0.084618 *)
```

Comment: Thanks @Pickett, the timing is really impressive. I never used `Compile` before, so thanks for that also. I was wondering if it is possible to store the array as functions? For my case the `a`, `b` functions are parameter dependent and I have to produce this matrix for a particular set `p` and for different parameter values. With your syntax I can afford to generate the matrix for each parameter value, but I think storing the matrix in a functional form can be a bit faster!

Comment: @Sumit Could you elaborate on what you mean by "store the array as functions"? I will try to answer the question, but I don't quite understand it yet.

Comment: Sorry @Pickett for not making it clear. Let say a[x_]=Sin[k1 x] and b[x_]=Cos[k2 x]. So the final matrix will be something like `m1[k1_, k2_]  =
 SparseArray[{{1, 3} -> Sin[2.345 k1], {4, 2} -> Cos[5.678 k2],...}] (*= m[p]*)`. Now I can simply give the value of `k1` and `k2` and generate the whole matrix (`m1[k1,k2]`). This needs to evaluate perhaps few thousands terms only.

Comment: @Sumit I see, no that's not possible because the C language can't handle symbolic expressions. It has to receive and return numeric values (or another valid C data type).

Comment: Hi @Pickett. Is it possible to generalise your method if each element of `p` is a vector? If you are interested, I post it as a  new question [How to use Compile to generate an n×n array using n vectors](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88527/how-to-use-compile-to-generate-an-n-times-n-array-using-n-vectors).

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly memory efficient, but ~20X faster than your first, ~5X faster than your non-parallel map (which, btw, does not produce the same results as your first) on n=1000...

```
oo = Flatten@Outer[Subtract, p, p];
aoo = Abs@oo;
rl = (Length@p)^2;
aa = Pick[Range@rl, Unitize@Clip[aoo, {2, 3}, {0, 0}], 1];
bb = Pick[Range@rl, Unitize@Clip[aoo, {5, 6}, {0, 0}], 1];
sa = Partition[SparseArray[Join[aa, bb] -> Join[a /@ oo[[aa]], b /@ oo[[bb]]], rl],Length@p];
```

Just a cobbled-up idea, perhaps something in there useful to you...