# Get position from one list and choose element of another list in Compile

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, compile, filtering, conditional

How can do it?

```
t = {};
f = 
 Compile[{{l, _Integer}}, 
   Module[
     {list = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}}, 
     Map[AppendTo[t, list[[#]] &], l]]; 
     t
   ];
```

> CompiledFunction::cfta

there is two related question: [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/function-does-not-compile-with-greater-in-it) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103720/compilecplist-error-from-mapthread).

**Update**:
 with help of Sumit ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88527/how-to-use-compile-to-generate-an-n-times-n-array-using-n-vectors)) I write another function but still there is problem with `Sequence@@`.

```
Compile[{{l, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{positions = {1, 2, 4}},
   Table[KroneckerDelta[#1, 
       Sequence @@ Flatten@Position[list, #2]]*#2 &[x, y], 
      {x,positions}, {y, l}]
   ]
]
```

Or this:

```
  f = Compile[{{r, _Integer, 2}},
  Table[
    Map[KroneckerDelta[p, Position[r, #][[1]]]*# &, r], {p, {2, 4}}]]
```

Comment: You're practicing to use `Compile`? If not, why not simply use `t = list[[l]]` ?

Comment: Yes, Of course , there is not any problem without compile.@xzczd

Comment: the simpler question is : How to choose some elements of given list to compile by their position.

Comment: this might be helpful http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88527/how-to-use-compile-to-generate-an-n-times-n-array-using-n-vectors

Comment: Then are you just looking for a compiled function or you want to insist on `AppendTo`, `Map` etc.? If the former, then how about `f = Compile[{{l, _Integer, 1}}, Module[{list = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}}, list[[l]]]]; t = f[{1, 2, 1}]`?

Comment: I want to use the generated list in compile function, Map and AppendTo are not the matter but the list should be usable in compile again. @xzczd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the *global* symbol `t` within a compiled function. This is not going to work like you expect it. What you probably want is the following simple function providing that I understood you correctly:

```
f = Compile[{{l, _Integer, 1}}, Module[{
     list = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}},
     t = Most[{{1}}]},
    t = Map[list[[#]] &, l];
    t
  ]
];
```

No `AppendTo` needed and it gives you a local `t` that you can use inside the compiled function itself.

```
f[{1, 2, 1, 3}]
(* {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 3}} *)
```

Please pay attention that you have to help `Compile` determining the correct data types. I explicitly defined `l` as a *list of numbers* and even the expression

```
Most[{{1}}]
```

only gives the empty list `{}`, BUT the compiler saw that I had a *list of integer lists* and therefore, assumes `t` should have exactly this type.

Comment: Actually if one insists on `AppendTo` then `Map` will fail, not sure about the exact reason though.

Comment: I have another question but I don't know ask it as a new question or not, actually the list that I want to choose from it is a global variable. I try it to give the list to Compile (function) but it produce another problem, the function should be used in FixedPoint. but I don't know how to give 2 arguments function to FixedPoint.

Comment: Ask it as new question and give your short algorithm *without* using `Compile`, so that people understand what you try to do.

Comment: and another problem: the elements of former list are not in same size. for example {{1},{1,3,4,2},{4,2}}

Comment: This is called a *ragged array* and it cannot be used as natural inside `Compile` as you might think. There are ways to solve this, but that are advanced and you already need to be quite confident with `Compile` to use them. In general, just think of it as impossible to either give ragged arrays as input or return them.

Comment: @halirutan thanks I asked the question here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104004/manipulating-some-lists-in-compile[link]