# Manipulating Some Lists in Compile

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, compile, filtering, conditional

Consider a list of lists, such as:

```
Z={{1,4,3},{2,1,3},{3,1,4}}
```

`Z` is an $n \times n$ matrix (here $3 \times 3$) which represent sites. Each site has a random number.  Here we have 9 sites that indexed with: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

```
Neighbors={{1, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 5, 4}, {3, 2}, {4, 7, 2}, {5, 6, 2, 8, 7, 9}, {6, 5, 9}, {7, 4, 5}, {8, 9, 5}, {9, 8, 6, 5}}
```

Each site have some random neighbors. In Neighbors's list first element of each member represent index of the site, and others represent neighbors of that site, for example here neighbors of site 2 are 1,3,5,4.

```
t={{1,0,1},{1,1,0},{0,0,0}}
```

Here $t$ is a list same as `Z` but just have 0 at first. In every step we choose some sites and adding 1 to the neighbors of that sites (here we choosing site with index 2).

I want to write a Compile function (func) that create list `t`.
also I write two function `ijTok`, and `kToij` to transform index of sites in neighbors list to position of that site in `Z` or `t`.

At last we need to use `FixedPoint`:

```
FixedPoint[func,Z] or fixedPoint[func,z,neighbors]
```

I spent many hours on it and learn that Compile have some limitation. For example we not allow to use True,False value in it.
this is what I write without compile I need to write same thing in Compile:
Pseudo Code:

```
func[z_] := Module[{t= z /. x_Integer -> 0},
  POSij = Position of chosen sites from  Z ;
  POSk = Map[ijTok, POSij];
  Neighborsij = Position of neighbors of chosen sites in {i, j} form;
  t += 1 just for sites that are neighbors of chosen sites ;
  Return[t];
  ]
```

Mathematica form of above pseudo code:

```
    Func[Z_] := Module[{list = Z/.x_Integer->0},
  POSij =Position[Z, #& (* choosing some special sites*)];
  POSk = Map[ijTok, POSij];
  NeiNodeij = 
   Map[Map[kTOij, 
      Drop[Neighbors[[#]], 1]] &, POSk];
  t=Map[Map[list[[Sequence @@ #]]++ &, #] &, Neighborsij], 0]
    ]
```

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103950/get-position-from-one-list-and-choose-element-of-another-list-in-compile/103975#103975) is my previous question.

Comment: I tried several version of this algorithm in compile, but each one have a special difficulty and don't work correctly.

Comment: "return another list that created with `t` and `Z`", how is the "another list" created? I think you'd better describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: this part is not difficult and I did it in compile my self, some special sites in z  should be minus and then adding each corresponding site's value (in z and t) together.@xzczd

Comment: Well, to be honest, I think you're in the wrong way. `Compile` is the toy of experienced _Mathematica_ user and one should gain a good enough understanding for "coding in _Mathematica_" before trying it. I think you'd better describe what you're trying to do in a more clear way so we can help figuring out if there's a better way to code.

Comment: I can write basically different code without ragged list, but it need some more effort, which is better changing the algorithm or adapting former algorithm (with ragged list) with Compile.

Comment: If you insist on compiling the `topple[r]`, at least provide the definition of `r`, `emptl`, `degZ`, `ijTok`, `L`, `NeighNode`and `tcount`, without all these one can not tell how to compile the function.

Comment: thanks for your attention , I update the question.

Comment: If I understand the pseudo code correctly, it's just creating `t` described above? Then how about `func[z_, nei_] := Module[{t = ConstantArray[0, Length@Flatten@z]}, t[[Rest@nei]] = 1; Partition[t, Length@z]]; func[Z, Neighbors[[2]]]`

Comment: it is so good @xzczd thanks.

Comment: How can I find some references that illustrated working with Compile? @xzczd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let me kill the unanswered question. Your `func` can be simplified to:

```
func[z_, nei_] := Module[{t = ConstantArray[0, Length@Flatten@z]}, 
                         t[[Rest@nei]] = 1; Partition[t, Length@z]]; 
func[Z, Neighbors[[2]]]
```

If you still want to compile it, you just need a little modification:

```
cfunc = Compile[{{z, _Integer, 2}, {nei, _Integer, 1}}, 
  Module[{t = Table[0, {Length@Flatten@z}]}, (t[[#]] = 1) & /@ Rest@nei; 
   Partition[t, Length@z]]]
func[Z, Neighbors[[2]]]
```

But according to my personal experience, pure list manipulation code (by *pure* I mean code that doesn't include algebraic operation) usually won't be sped up much (if any) by `Compile`, functions for list manipulation in *Mathematica* have already been highly optimized.