# How to use Compile to generate an $n×n$ array using $n$ tensors with both Real and Integer element

Tags: compile, list-manipulation

This is an extension of my earlier questions [Faster use of Condition for a large array (see the example)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87032/faster-use-of-condition-for-a-large-array-see-the-example)
and
[How to use Compile to generate an $n\times n$ array using $n$ vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88527/how-to-use-compile-to-generate-an-n-times-n-array-using-n-vectors) . In this case each point is characterised by a pair of indices.

Consider this `Array`.

```
n1 = n2 = 30;
n = 9;
data = Flatten[Table[{RandomInteger[{1, n}, 2], {1. i, 1. j}},
{i, n1}, {j, n2}],1];
```

So each element of `data` is {{`Integer`,`Integer`},{`Real`,`Real`}}. Then I define 3 matrices.

```
P = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
Q = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
R = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
```

And I have to create another matrix from `data` like this

```
m1 = Table[
{s1, t1} = x[[1]]; {s2, t2} = y[[1]];
dr = x[[2]] - y[[2]];
Which[
 Abs[Norm[dr] - 0.] < 0.001, R[[s1, t1]],
 Abs[Norm[dr] - 1.] < 0.001, Q[[Abs[s1 - s2] + 1, Abs[t1 - t2] + 1]],
 Abs[Norm[dr] - Sqrt[2]] < 0.001, P[[Abs[s1 - s2] + 1, Abs[t1 - t2] + 1]],
 True, 0],
{x, data}, {y, data}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {17.569614, Null}

That is, depending on what is distance between $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ point, the $ij^{th}$ element of `m1` will be given by an element of `P`,`Q` or `R` matrix.

As much I know, in such cases `Compile` gives faster result. So I try in this way (based on the  [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88527/how-to-use-compile-to-generate-an-n-times-n-array-using-n-vectors?answertab=oldest#tab-top) to a similar problem by Pickett)

```
TensorRank[data]
```

> 3

```
m = Compile[{{sys, _Real, 3}},
Table[
Assuming[{s1, t1, s2, t2} \[Element] Integers,
{{s1, t1} = IntegerPart@x[[1]], {s2, t2} = IntegerPart@y[[1]]}];
dr = x[[2]] - y[[2]];
Which[
 Abs[Norm[dr] - 0.] < 0.001, R[[s1, t1]],
 Abs[Norm[dr] - 1.] < 0.001, Q[[Abs[s1 - s2] + 1, Abs[t1 - t2] + 1]],
 Abs[Norm[dr] - Sqrt[2]] < 0.001, P[[Abs[s1 - s2] + 1, Abs[t1 - t2] + 1]],
 True, 0],
{x, sys}, {y, sys}],
CompilationTarget -> "C"];

m2 = m[data]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {48.353723, Null}

It is almost same time with `"RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"`.

However if I remove `Assuming`, so it treats `s1,t1,s2,t2` as `Reals`, it produces an error message

> CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression Compile`GetElement[{7,5},1] should be a machine-size integer. >>
>
> CompiledFunction::cfexe: Could not complete external evaluation; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>

and then it takes same time as the `Table` (~18sec).

What would be the correct and faster way to do this?

Comment: Try this: `Needs["CompiledFunctionTools\`"]; CompilePrint[m]`. You will see many calls to `MainEvaluate` in your generated code that indicate calls to the main *Mathematica* evaluator for functions / expressions that cannot be compiled. You will want to take a look at [How to Compile effectively?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1803/27951) as well.

Comment: Could you describe in words what you want to accomplish? I can't quite follow your implementation.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB. I know this question and the suggestions, they are indeed quite helpful. Regarding what I am trying to do - I have a set of n points characterized by two indices  (first two integers) and coordinates (second pair of real numbers). Now I am trying to construct an nxn matrix whose ij-th element is determined by the coordinate and index of i-th and j-th point. Depending on the distance between ith and jth point (dr= 0.,1.,Sqrt[2.]) the ij-th element of m matrix will be given by an element of P,Q or R matrix, as described by the `Which`. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how to answer this question without sounding discouraging. I cannot go into every detail but I still want to help you. Basically, you did several things wrong:

- using global variables inside `Compile` which makes that the compiled function calls back to the *Mathematica Kernel* to ask for instance what the definition of `R` is. Compiled functions need to be completely self-contained (until you are knowledgeable enough to know when to break this rule). This means, every definition, variable, etc that is not given in the arguments to `Compile` needs to be injected. Marco already gave you the correct links for further reading.
- local variables need to put inside a `Module` (or `With` if appropriate)
- not all functions of *Mathematica* can be used inside a compiled construct. You can check the [list of compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/187) functions. When a function like `Integrate` cannot be compiled, then (again) the compiled function calls back to the Kernel asking him to evaluate certain parts.
- *type inference*, which means how the compiler decides whether `dr` for instance is a real or integer variable is especially difficult inside `Compile`. The easiest way is to write `s1=0` in the `Module` declaration to indicate `s1` is an integer. Or `s1=0.0` to make it a real. This issue was [discussed here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845/187) in on a different occasion.
- Use `CompilePrint` from the `` <<CompiledFunctionTools` `` package to check if there are `MainEvaluate` calls in your compiled code that indicate that the Kernel is called.

In conclusion one can say, this all takes a lot of experience and it is never (except for the most simple cases) a solution to just write `Compile` around an expression. That being said, I have corrected your code. You can get my complete notebook by evaluating :

```
Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2KvJ.png"]
```

or you copy the pieces when reading the explanations below:

```
n1 = n2 = 30;
n = 9;
data = Flatten[
   Table[{RandomInteger[{1, n}, 2], {1. i, 1. j}}, {i, n1}, {j, n2}], 
   1];

P = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
Q = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
R = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];

With[{P = P, Q = Q, R = R},
 fc1 = Compile[{{sys, _Integer, 3}},
    Module[{s1 = 0, t1 = 0, s2 = 0, t2 = 0, dr},
     Table[
      {s1, t1} = x[[1]];
      {s2, t2} = y[[1]];
      dr = Sqrt[#.#] &[x[[2]] - y[[2]]];
      Which[
       Abs[dr - 0.] < 0.001,
       R[[s1, t1]],
       Abs[dr - 1.] < 0.001,
       Q[[Abs[s1 - s2] + 1, Abs[t1 - t2] + 1]],
       Abs[dr - Sqrt[2]] < 0.001,
       P[[Abs[s1 - s2] + 1, Abs[t1 - t2] + 1]],
       True, 0.0], {x, sys}, {y, sys}]
     ], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
 ]
```

This function gives the same result as your `Table` call but only takes

```
fc1[data]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.218867, Null} *)
```

0.2 seconds to run. There is still room for improvement. Your compiled function consists basically of a `Table` having two iterators `x` and `y`. What you could do is re-use the code above and adapt it so that you create a function that

> iterates only over `y` and does the iteration over `x` in parallel.

To understand how this works, please see my answer in [Use Compile to improve performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91792/187)

```
With[{P = P, Q = Q, R = R},
 f2 = Compile[{{sys, _Integer, 3}, {x, _Integer, 2}},
    Module[{s1 = 0, t1 = 0, s2 = 0, t2 = 0, dr},
     Table[
      {s1, t1} = x[[1]];
      {s2, t2} = y[[1]];
      dr = Sqrt[#.#] &[x[[2]] - y[[2]]];
      Which[
       Abs[dr - 0.] < 0.001,
       R[[s1, t1]],
       Abs[dr - 1.] < 0.001,
       Q[[Abs[s1 - s2] + 1, Abs[t1 - t2] + 1]],
       Abs[dr - Sqrt[2]] < 0.001,
       P[[Abs[s1 - s2] + 1, Abs[t1 - t2] + 1]],
       True, 0.0], {y, sys}]
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ];
 ]
```

you have to call this function with `fc2[data, data]` and if you really put some effort in understanding what happens, then you will see why and how it works.

This brings an additional factor of 2

```
<< GeneralUtilities`

AccurateTiming[fc1[data]]/AccurateTiming[fc2[data, data]]
(* 2.06425 *)
```

Comment: “This issue was [discussed here] in on a different occasion.” You missed a link :)

Comment: @xzczd That was left as exercise for the attentive reader. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks @halirutan. That is very helpful for a beginner like me.